# File upload jquery instead of preview the file it show the link in the below new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Working on Jquery file upload I don't want to use any plugin.Using Pure Jquery / javascript. Instead of preview the file I want the link **(View)** needs to be display once the image & pdf  upload if the user click the link it has to open in the new page.

Here is my HTML Code

Any guidance here please

```
<div class="mob_pass">
    <label class="ctm_fnt">Attach document</label>
    <br>
    <div class="custom-file-input">
        <input type="file">
        <input type="text" class="txt_field ctm_widt" placeholder="Attached File">
        <button class="cst_select">
            <i class="fa  fa-rotate-90"></i> Attach
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Kindly help me.

Thanks In advance

Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/uvL57wtn/)

Comment: what are you using at code behind ? php or c#

Comment: no code behind simple jquery and javascript it was just a form where i need to upload

Comment: do want it to be sent by email ?

Comment: no once the image upload if i click view button i need to open the image or pdf in new window finally the user the submit 

i am using ajax

Comment: if you are using ajax then there should be a script running behind

Comment: we can try with ajax i am not using right now but we can try

Comment: where do you want to deploy the application ?

Comment: in the server once the file upload

Comment: which language does your server support ? php or asp.net ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88358/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-shaminder-s-aujla).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your markup :

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="preview">View</a>
```

In JS, capture the event of the input change, get the preview and set the `a`'s `href` to the data URL that you get.

Hide the `a` initially (when no file is selected), and show it again once you have something to show.

```
var $preview = $(".preview");
$preview.hide();

$("input").on("change", function(){

  var files = this.files;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function(e){
    $preview.attr("href", e.target.result);
    $preview.show();
  };

  fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
});
```

JSBin : http://jsbin.com/duziwukuro/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi @Drown thanks for your effort is that possible can i able to upload pdf also here. please guide me

Comment: Sorry  @Drown if i want to store this file in a particular directory is this also possible with this if yes kindly guide me how to do that

Comment: I am getting this.files undefined. While js bin works fine.